# how to visible layout in android

Tags: android, android-fragments, sharedpreferences, visibility

am working on android application in which there is two activity that is main activity and mode activity. my first activity is main activity have some invisible icon, [image]
       and second activity is mode activity .when i click on button in my second activity[image] i cam back my first activity i want that invisible icon should visible. [image]

```
enter code here

  pro.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            autobtn.setImageResource(R.drawable.auyto);
            pro.setImageResource(R.drawable.proactiv);
            Intent it = new Intent(ModeActivity.this, Mainactivity.class);
            startActivity(it);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can hide view using

```
yourView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

You can get the reference to your view by using findViewByID :) 
and when you want to get it back just say `yourView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);`

As per your question,in your Mode activity's onCreate or onStart you can hide your invisible icons like

```
    @Override
    protected void onStart(){
        super.onStart();
        yourView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
```

and in onClickListener of the button of your mode activity you can make the button visible. In onclickListener of your button put the code

```
   yourView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

Thats all.If you want the icons to appear and hide on alternate taps on same button (use button like toggle) then put the below code

```
 if (yourView.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
      yourView.setVisibility(View.GONE); 
  } else {
      // Either gone or invisible
      yourView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); 
  }
```

Hope it helps :)

Comment: where can i use these code in main activity is it onResume()

Comment: you can put it in onStart as I have shown or in onCreate anywhere you want sir :) just make sure that you get the reference to icon before calling the yourView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); where your view is your icon :)

Comment: everytime your main activity gets loaded onStart() and onCreate gets called in your case :) so its ok to put it in any of this method :) anything specific why you want to put it in onResume?? it should work fine there too though :)

Comment: @ Sandeep Bhandari suppose i clicked on pro button in pro mode it back to main activity and hide button should b visible like in picture red square

Comment: am really sorry sir, I just got confused. My earlier answer is perfectly rite for your situation. Hope you still have the code and as per your question what is modeVal its a integer variable, whose value you will pass in intent by adding extra like I had shown earlier. Based on the value you can decide if you are coming from mode activity or directly coming to main activity :)

Answer (score 0):

To make your **icon** visible, you can use

```
icon.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are using SurfaceView , if yes then keep your SurfaceView in FrameLayout and over the SurfaceView place the another View

Like this

```
 <FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <SurfaceView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:gravity="bottom"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        >

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_logo"/>

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_logo"/>

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_logo"/>


    </LinearLayout>


</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: just overlap your SurfaceView with some another View

Comment: its ok please please look my picture that i post in first picture there hide button and when i click on pro in my second picture i came back first activity and i want these button that i show in red square thats it

Comment: try this one... just replace ic_logo with your images